# Can't parse this JSON in php

Tags: php, json, yql

I'm trying to get off some mails from Yahoo Query Language using OAuth, everything is fine and alright, except, YQL returns JSON, and somehow I'm not able to parse it!

I'm able to parse simple JSONs like

```
'{"hello":"world"}'
```

but not this one:

```
{
"query": {
    "count": 1,
    "created": "2012-08-11T19:22:51Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "results": {
        "result": {
            "messageInfo": [
                {
                    "from": {
                        "name": "account-services-us@cc.yahoo-inc.com"
                    },
                    "subject": "Success! You have shared your Yahoo! information"
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "name": "account-services-in@cc.yahoo-inc.com"
                    },
                    "subject": "Success! You have shared your Yahoo! information."
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "name": "account-services-in@cc.yahoo-inc.com"
                    },
                    "subject": "Success! You have shared your Yahoo! information."
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "name": "Yahoo!"
                    },
                    "subject": "Welcome to Yahoo!"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

I tried validating it in 
    http://jsonlint.com/

and it's valid!

Edit: I need to display 'from:name' and 'subject' in a table like structure.

The code snippet I wrote is this:

```
$sdata = call_yql(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
               $access_token, $access_token_secret,
               false, true);
$json_data = json_encode($sdata);
$mails = json_decode($json_data);
print_r($mails->query);
```

The Error i get is:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\yahoo\txtweb\yql.php       on line 21
```

Comment: Define "not able to parse it". What code do you use? What result do you get? What errors are reported?

Comment: What errors do you get (if any)?  I just copied that and called `json_decode` and it successfully returned a `stdClass` object to me with all the correct data.

Comment: If you are using `json_decode()`, try running `json_last_error()` to see what's wrong. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/ehd6Q9QB

Comment: have you looked if there are white spaces or non breaking spaces that could be trimmed off the string or whatever which would make the string bugged when they're there?

Comment: Sushas, if you use json_decode($json_data,true), you can get the data in PHP array form.

Comment: What result do you get if you remove the line `$json_data = json_encode($sdata);` and change `$json_data` on the next line to `$sdata`?

Comment: when i remove that line - and try doing $mails->{'query'} Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\yahoo\txtweb\yql.php on line 21

Comment: What exactly is `$sdata`? Give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this url:-

[Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

see also this url

http://collegewires.com/parsing-json-with-php/

or try it

To iterator over a multidimensional array, you can use the [RecursiveArrayIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957133/php-spl-reference-documentation/4218646#4218646)

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: i have add improve my answer please take a look.

Comment: Gives me this:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead' in C:\xampp\htdocs\yahoo\txtweb\yql.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\yahoo\txtweb\yql.php(22): ArrayIterator->__construct('{"query":{"coun...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\yahoo\txtweb\yql.php on line 22

Comment: Just remove the double-encoding - see @Kaii's answer.