# PHP multidimensional array to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, json

So im trying to figure out the best way to get MySql table data into either a multidimensional PHP array or convert that multidimensional array into a json string.

Essentially what im trying to do is have a php include that returns the JSON string so i can iterate through it. I am needing a single key with multiple values, so im not 100% sure that im headed in the right direction.

I want to assign multiple values to the same key, for example:

```
[{"key1": "package1", "package2", "package3"}, {"key2": "package1", "package2", "package3", "package4"}]
```

I think that is not going to work right? Because i dont have any type of index's?

Comment: Have you tried json_encode? That should have handled everything for you. (It will output the json in the right format, not the one you specified, which is incorrect as json arrays should be represented differently.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not valid JSON. The structure you are looking for would be something like:

```
[
 {"key1": ["package1", "package2", "package3"]},
 {"key2": ["package1", "package2", "package3", "package4"}]
          ^ An array as the value to the key "key1", "key2", etc..
]
```

At the PHP side, you would need something like:

1. For every row fetched from MySQL

   - `$arr[$key]` = <new array>
   - for each package:

     - append package to `$arr[$key]`
2. echo out `json_encode($arr)`

Comment: My ultimate goal is to have each item in the 'db' table as a key and then for each key have all the various 'values' that are in the database under that 'key/table'

Comment: Trying to get the second array appended to the first..kicking my arse

Answer (score 1):

JS arrays have an implicit array keying, starting at index 0. What you've got is a perfectly valid JS array, the equivalent of having written:

```
var x = []; // create new empty array
x[0] = {"key1": .... }; // first object
x[1] = {"key2": ....} // second object
```

Note that the contents of your `{}` sub-objects is NOT valid.

You should never EVER built a JSON string by hand. It's too unreliable and easy to mess up. It's just easier to use a native data structure (php arrays/objects), then `json_encode()` them. Ditto on the other end of the process - don't decode the string manually. Convert to a native data structure (e.g. `json_decode()`, `JSON.parse()`) and then deal with the native structure directly.

essentially, JSON is a transmission format, not a manipulation format.