# How in jquery (json) to call/name php array element

Tags: json

This is array in external php file

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CurrencyAbbreviation] => AUD
            [CurrencyRate] => 0.50600000
            [DateOfCurrencyRate] => 2013-07-11
            [Units] => 1
        )
)
```

Want to call for example `CurrencyRate`

Tried code like `$('#currency_load').html(data.CurrencyRate);` (Chrome F12 get 404 error).

For comparison. If php array is like this

```
$arr = array ('item1'=>"I love jquery4u",'item2'=>"You love jQuery4u",'item3'=>"We love jQuery4u");
```

and `json` `$('#currency_load').html(data.item1);`

then all works.

Do I need somehow to modify php array?

Comment: Your array has a nested array within it, which cannot simply be ignored. `data[0].CurrencyRate`

Comment: Yes, nested. Any solution to get element from nested array? Or no solution? Seems only solution is to modify array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205877/php-multidimensional-array-to-json