# Convert php multidimensional array to json format to use in Jquery $.post

Tags: php, json

With `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` get such array

```
$array = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FinalCurrencyRate] => 0.000062
        )
)
```

Need to `json_encode` to use in

```
$.post("__02.php", { 'currency': currency }, function(data, success) {
$('#currency_load').html(data.FinalCurrencyRate);
$('#currency_load0').html(data.FinalCurrencyRate0);
$('#currency_load1').html(data.FinalCurrencyRate1);//and so on
}, "json");
```

If simply `echo json_encode($array);` then does not work.

Need to convert to json format array like this:

`$arr = array ('FinalCurrencyRate'=>"0.000062");`

To convert to json format, wrote such code

```
$json_array = "{";
$flag_comma = 0;
foreach($array as $i =>$array_modified) {

if ($flag_comma == 0) {
$json_array .="'FinalCurrencyRate". $i."'=>'". $array_modified[FinalCurrencyRate]. "'";
$flag_comma = 1;
}
else {
$json_array .=", 'FinalCurrencyRate". $i."'=>'". $array_modified[FinalCurrencyRate]. "'";
}

}
$json_array .= "}";
```

Then `echo json_encode($json_array);`. And only one `echo json_encode`.

But does not work.

Understand that there are errors in code to convert to json format. What need to correct, please?

Comment: Just a little question back: Do you know what the 404 status code stands for?

Comment: I see that 404 is Not Found.

Comment: OK. But the question is about php code convert php array json format array. There is some errors in code and need to understand what to correct.

Comment: @user2465936 404 Not Found means that you are trying to access a page that doesn't exist. Most likely you made a typo in your url. `json_encode` is perfectly able to turn a multidimensional array into a json string.

Comment: No. url is correct. I tried with json format array and all works. Suppose in my case 404 means that can not find `FinalCurrencyRate`

Comment: I guess you're doing `echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: @user2465936 No, that is **not** what a 404 error means. A 404 error is invoked by your httpd service. It never executes your page.

Comment: Please, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421959/how-in-jquery-json-to-call-name-php-array-element and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205877/php-multidimensional-array-to-json

Comment: Question is not about 404. Question is that one array works with `json_encode` and another array does not work. The another array must convert to such type of array that works with `json_encode`

Comment: @user2465936: Please replay the AJAX request with curl on the command-line and present us request headers, response headers and the response body in plain text. Until then I'm voting to put your question on hold because you don't show a minimum understanding required to post questions here on Stackoverflow (yes I know that sounds harsh, however I just do that because I'm missing information and I also have said which information and it's also something common developer tools like in Google chrome support you with).

Comment: @hakre sorry, no such knowledge. Do I need to use something like `var the_url = 'curl -u username:password "http://www.myurl.com/api/get"';`? Actually, started to examine based on @koala_dev advice and for `$array[0]` all works. Just need to do the same for whole array.

Comment: @hakre. Request header is `GET /javascript/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1
Host: www.url.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.url.com/__test_what_ajax_passes.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,lv;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4` Now understand that 404 is related with `jquery.min.map`. But if regarding question, then used @koala_dev advice and all works. Suppose, that `jquery.min.map` is called from some other javascript (will find and correct)

Comment: Here is some information related to missing `jquery.min.map` https://github.com/kibio/kibio-common/issues/25

Comment: sorry was offline. there is a feature in google chrome you can copy the ajax request as curl command and then replay it isolated on the command-line. https://coderwall.com/p/-fdgoq https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/317183238026186752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to return the first row form your array, then you just need to do this

```
echo json_encode($array[0]);
```

**UPDATE**

I think I see what you're trying to do now, you're trying to append the index to the `FinalCurrencyRate` key in each row. No need to do that, what you should do is change your javascript code to look like this:

```
$('#currency_load0').html(data[0].FinalCurrencyRate);
$('#currency_load1').html(data[1].FinalCurrencyRate);//and so on
```

Comment: Want to return whole array. May be to use inside `foreach` `$array[$i]`. Thanks for advice. I will try (may be to modify array).