# Parsing Arrays in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Can anyone suggest an elegant way to change an array of the form below to an array containing only the primary keys, using php?

```
[{
    "PrimaryKey": "489",
    "name": "Ted"
}, {
    "PrimaryKey": "488",
    "name": "Bill"
}, {
    "PrimaryKey": "487",
    "singleFbId": "Joe"
}]
```

Comment: Looks like JSON. How about a json parser? Or you probably mean "traversing". Arrays are traversed in PHP using `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = '[{
    "PrimaryKey": "489",
    "name": "Ted"
}, {
    "PrimaryKey": "488",
    "name": "Bill"
}, {
    "PrimaryKey": "487",
    "singleFbId": "Joe"
}]';

$array = json_decode($data, TRUE);

print_r($array);
```