# Ajax form: Fallback styling

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an Ajax form. Now I want to supply a solid fallback if the user has JavaScript deactivated.

So far it works also without JavaScript, but the user then simply sees the JSON string as a result printed on blank white without styling because of

`echo json_encode( $arr );`

How do I add styling to this? Do I have to `echo` a whole HTML page? Is it possible to enable a redirect for JS disabled or something?

The whole PHP bit looks like this:

```
if ( !empty( $invalidFieldArray ) ) {     
    // validation errors
    $arr = array( "status" => "error" , "data" => $invalidFieldArray );
    echo json_encode( $arr );      
} else {
    // all ok
    $arr = array( "status" => "success" );
    echo json_encode( $arr );
}
```

Comment: You need to show an example

Comment: [Write something in PHP in the original page to parse the JSON and format it.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4343596/901048)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HTML and AJAX

You could use a different `action` URL in your `<form>` than the one used by AJAX. That way, you can have a normal working `<form>` fallback which outputs HTML.

### X-Requested-With

Or, if you want to use only one URL for both methods, then you can have a look at the `X-Requested-With` header sent, and identify an AJAX request by checking it against the value `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  /* It's AJAX */
} else {
  /* HTML fallback */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
<form action="some.url?js=false"...
```

set the action with a flag saying there is no JavaScript available

Then use JavaScript to remove it

```
$('form').attr('action', "some.url");
```

Then on the server side you can check for `$_GET[js]` if its not set just echo the json otherwise a full page.