# Get JSON object from URL

Tags: php, json

I have a URL that returns a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "expires_in":5180976,
    "access_token":"AQXzQgKTpTSjs-qiBh30aMgm3_Kb53oIf-VA733BpAogVE5jpz3jujU65WJ1XXSvVm1xr2LslGLLCWTNV5Kd_8J1YUx26axkt1E-vsOdvUAgMFH1VJwtclAXdaxRxk5UtmCWeISB6rx6NtvDt7yohnaarpBJjHWMsWYtpNn6nD87n0syud0"
}
```

I want to get JSON object from the URL and then the `access_token` value.

So how can I retrieve it through PHP?

Comment: `json_decode($your_string)` should do the trick

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php

Answer (score 409, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_here');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->access_token;
```

For this to work, `file_get_contents` requires that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. This can be done at runtime by including:

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
```

You can also use [`curl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) to get the URL. To use curl, you can use the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701318/475125):

```
$ch = curl_init();
// IMPORTANT: the below line is a security risk, read https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software
// in most cases, you should set it to true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url_here');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj->access_token;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that first how do I get this string from the url then access the json object?

Comment: The error came on this line 
echo $obj['access_token'];
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in F:\wamp\www\sandbox\linkedin\test.php on line 22

Comment: @user2199343 If you want to use the result as array, use ", true" in json_decode function. See my answer for example.

Comment: file_get_contents('url'); There is an error referring to this

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&amp;code=AQSuFANDoXm9OkKT3oH_1ReZ0CZVJGuG5rBncJVWR8QRHihxlDryCTs7oiWN3BViVJJn_QIg7AzMp4cXz98F_9CV0jIkNHoEDMb7pUcO2OYKGb5Bchg&amp;redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8088/sandbox/linkedin/test.php&amp;client_id=1ba8ogpm9e05&amp;client_secret=n7GN09I3F2L3IJD1) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in F:\wamp\www\sandbox\linkedin\test.php on line 20

Comment: That's a different issue, you should open up another question for it.

Comment: It's now fixed. I just logged in again from my linkedin account. Thank you for the asisstance.

Comment: you can put this line at the top `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);` to enable `allow_url_fopen` at runtime.

Comment: Curl complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700960/how-to-use-curl-to-get-json-data-and-decode-the-data?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Web_Developer i will add this to the post

Comment: does curl not need allow_url_fopen enabled? Or both of them do need it?

Comment: [You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software). It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score 28):

```
$url = 'http://.../.../yoururl/...';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo $obj['access_token'];
```

PHP also can use properties with dashes:

```
garex@ustimenko ~/src/ekapusta/deploy $ psysh
Psy Shell v0.4.4 (PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $q = new stdClass;
=> <stdClass #000000005f2b81c80000000076756fef> {}
>>> $q->{'qwert-y'} = 123
=> 123
>>> var_dump($q);
class stdClass#174 (1) {
  public $qwert-y =>
  int(123)
}
=> null
```

Comment: i would prefer this answer on the chosen answer for 1 reason only
the parsed json could contain index with dash character
ex: {"full-name":"khalil","familiy-name":"whatever"}
decoding as array will keep you on the safe side

Answer (score 22):

You could use PHP's [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) function:

```
$url = "http://urlToYourJsonFile.com";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
echo "My token: ". $json_data["access_token"];
```

Comment: Good example but he method is called `json_decode` not `$json_decode`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to read about the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

Here you go:

```
$json = '{"expires_in":5180976,"access_token":"AQXzQgKTpTSjs-qiBh30aMgm3_Kb53oIf-VA733BpAogVE5jpz3jujU65WJ1XXSvVm1xr2LslGLLCWTNV5Kd_8J1YUx26axkt1E-vsOdvUAgMFH1VJwtclAXdaxRxk5UtmCWeISB6rx6NtvDt7yohnaarpBJjHWMsWYtpNn6nD87n0syud0"}';
//OR $json = file_get_contents('http://someurl.dev/...');

$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj-> access_token);

//OR

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($arr['access_token']);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
// Get the string from the URL
$json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452');

// Decode the JSON string into an object
$obj = json_decode($json);

// In the case of this input, do key and array lookups to get the values
var_dump($obj->results[0]->formatted_address);
```

Comment: Prefer code block formatting for code, and explanatory comments, especially if the code doesn't specifically answer the question directly (in this case there are different key names etc.)

Comment: Where has this been copied from? What is the source? It looks like drive by, google the question, and blindly paste the first search result as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url_here');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj->access_token;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has already been answered multiple times! Please elaborate on how your answer is different and improves the others, instead of simply dumping some code.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` was not fetching the data from a URL. Then I tried `curl` and it was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Our solution, adding some validations to response, so we are sure we have a well-formed JSON object in the **$json** variable:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (! $result) {
    return false;
}

$json = json_decode(utf8_encode($result));
if (empty($json) || json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution only works for the following cases:

If you are mistaking a multidimensional array into a single one:

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_json'); // Get the JSON content
$objhigher=json_decode($json); // Cconverts to an object
$objlower = $objhigher[0]; // If the JSON response is multidimensional, this lowers it
echo "<pre>"; // Box for code
print_r($objlower); // Prints the object with all key and values
echo $objlower->access_token; // Prints the variable
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `curl`, it sometimes gives you a 403 (access forbidden).

I solved by adding this line to emulate a browser.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
```

Comment: how do i get a string from a json array via php?

Answer (score 0):

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.xxxSite/get_quote/ajaxGetQuoteJSON.jsp?symbol=IRCTC&series=EQ');
//Set the GET method by giving 0 value and for POST set as 1
//curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$data = json_decode($query, true);
curl_close($curl_handle);

//print complete object, just echo the variable not work so you need to use print_r to show the result
echo print_r( $data);
//at first layer
echo $data["tradedDate"];
//Inside the second layer
echo $data["data"][0]["companyName"];
```

Some time you might get 405, set the method type correctly.