# how to use curl in php to fetch value from a API

Tags: php, curl

I need to fetch data from an API using curl. As per the manual given the curl command should be like this

```
curl --user {YOUR_CLIENT_ID}:{YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET} https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses
```

Now while passing this command in pUTTY I am getting response and the data is displaying correctly but how to use this in a PHP page...am quiet new with cURL so any suggestion would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use cURL to get jSON data and decode the data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700960/how-to-use-curl-to-get-json-data-and-decode-the-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Will dump a beauty json <3
$fr=json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: @Babar...thanks for so prompt answer...ok I can fetch the data but can you please help me on how to fetch the title, url and price from these data for each course

Comment: use var_dump() to check structure of array and then get your desired data