# Got error using curl with github api

Tags: javascript, git, curl

I am using the curl to get git repositories information.
The command used is:

```
curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories?page=2&q=language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc
```

However, what I got is:

```
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Search",
      "field": "q",
      "code": "missing"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/search"
}
```

If I type directly the URL in the browser I obtain the correct JSON output, but when I use curl it fails. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [curl's documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) they actually only show in one of their examples:

> Get the main page from an IPv6 web server: `curl "http://[2001:1890:1112:1::20]/"`

**`""` are required to surround your URL** (due to its complexity). The command should be like this then:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?page=2&q=language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc"
```

If you want it to be downloaded to a file, then you can use the `-O` option:

```
curl -O "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?page=2&q=language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc"
```

If you're just [using windows](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win32&flav=-&ver=*) command line then you can run the `winssl`'s curl from [this zip](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/downloads/curl_X64_ssl.7z) (you need the ssl version for `https`).

However, I noticed your `javascript` tag in your question, so if you're planning to use curl on the client side, the [curl.js plugin](https://github.com/cujojs/curl) may be useful to you.

On the server side, if you are using **PHP** you can use this code:

```html
<?
    $url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?page=2&q=language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc";
    
    //  Initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);
    
    // Will dump a beauty json :3
    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
?>
```

This code was placed by ["none" in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701318/1326147), but in your case, you may need SSL verification enabled (so I commented it).

[curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) allows you to set these required options (and the URL itself) when using curl for getting a json file.