# GET request with authentication

Tags: php, json, rest

I have code which can POST a JSON to an API using authentication. I need to GET using authentication, yet most examples do not provide this information.

POST

```
public function putTest() {
    $username    = "user";
    $password    = "pass";
    $json_url    = "http://api.of.site.com";
    $json_string = "[]";

    $ch      = curl_init( $json_url );
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => "{$username}:{$password}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array( "Content-type: application/json" ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $json_string
    );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
}
```

GET (not working)

```
public function getTest() {
    $username    = "user";
    $password    = "pass";
    $json_url    = "http://api.of.site.com";

    $ch      = curl_init( $json_url );
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => "{$username}:{$password}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array( "Content-type: application/json" ),
    );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
}
```

What am I missing in my GET? Also I would like to keep it in this style rather than using [curl_setopt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701318/817379)

**EDIT:**
As reference, here is the command line version which works

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -u "username:pass" "http://api.site.name.com/thingtoget"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the POST needs `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array( "Content-type: application/json" ),` while the GET needs `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array( "Accept: application/json" ),` Makes sense reading it now.

```
public function getTest() {
    $username    = "user";
    $password    = "pass";
    $json_url    = "http://api.of.site.com";

    $ch      = curl_init( $json_url );
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => "{$username}:{$password}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array( "Accept: application/json" ),
    );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`

> Use CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH to specify the authentication method for HTTP
>   based connections

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERPWD.html

Comment: Tried this, I think I'm missing something else

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
```

An example:

```
public function call(array $data)
{
    $payload = json_encode($data['payload']);

    // Initialise the session
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Set API URL
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $data['url']);
    // Return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Include the header in the output
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    // Authentication
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'your_username:and_password');
    // Set request method
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $data['method']);

    if ($data['method'] == 'POST') {
        // Do a regular HTTP POST
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    }

    if ($data['method'] == 'POST' || $data['method'] == 'PUT') {
        // The full data to post in a HTTP POST operation
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload)
        ));
    }

    // Execute the request
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($curl);

    // If connection failed
    if (! $output) {
        return 'Curl connection failure.';
    }

    // Output the profile information, includes the header
    return $output;
}
```