# is it possible to embed a blogger comment?

Tags: javascript, json, blogger, feed

I have tow questions

1. is it possible to embed a blogger comment ?
2. how can I call blogger comments automatically . I wont to make like this code :

```html
<script src='www.exemple.com/feeds/IDscomments/comments/default?alt=json&amp;callback=showtopcomment&amp;max-results=5' type='text/javascript'>
```

using like this :
 ex :
data:comments.id 
data:comments.url ...

I use this api

```html
<script style=text/javascript src="http://helplogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/recent comments widget.js"></script>
<script style=text/javascript>
    var a_rc = 5;
    var m_rc = false;
    var n_rc = true;
    var o_rc = 100;
</script>
<script src=http://helplogger.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentcomments></script>

<style type="text/css"> 
.rcw-comments a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.rcw-comments {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    padding-top: 7px!important;
    padding-bottom: 7px!important;
}
</style>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: In order to do that you would have to call a specific web API. Are you trying to import posts from a specific blogging platform?

Comment: yes; but i need it  in comments

Answer (score 0):

First, web APIs can not be called as script source. The output from a web API is the data as a string. Because the web API does not know (and doesn't want to assume) how the data is being called, it just dumps it. That way a CURL request can handle it just as well as an AJAX. It is up to you to determine how best to request the data for your needs.

The blogger API for comments is very well handled. [Check it out.](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/comments)

If you update your question with some code and specific questions, I am positive the community will help with specific help.

[SO answer on PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700960/how-to-use-curl-to-get-json-data-and-decode-the-data)

[jQUery documentation on `getJson()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: i use this api
<script style=text/javascript src="http://helplogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/recent comments widget.js"></script>
<script style=text/javascript>
    var a_rc = 5;
    var m_rc = false;
    var n_rc = true;
    var o_rc = 100;
</script>
<script src=http://helplogger.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentcomments></script>