# How to format JSON response in PHP?

Tags: php, json

How do I format this JSON response to return only the "results". It is a returned value from a curl response. This was a full string that was returned.

```json
HTTP/1.0200OKCache-Control: no-cacheContent-Type: application/jsonDate: Thu,
07Jan201618: 33: 12GMT{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "**results**": {
    "national": {
      "goal_completions": 199,
      "sessions": 16251,
      "page_views": 23315,
      "users": 15691,
      "bounce_rate": 18.4784625
    },
    "regions": [
      {
        "region_id": 31,
        "region_name": "South",
        "data": {
          "ga_site_id": null,
          "goal_completions": null,
          "users": null,
          "sessions": null,
          "page_views": null,
          "bounce_rate": null
        }
      },
      {
        "region_id": 10,
        "region_name": "West",
        "data": {
          "ga_site_id": "4",
          "goal_completions": "199",
          "users": "15691",
          "sessions": "16251",
          "page_views": "23315",
          "bounce_rate": "73.91385000"
        }
      },
      {
        "region_id": 35,
        "region_name": "Northeast",
        "data": {
          "ga_site_id": null,
          "goal_completions": null,
          "users": null,
          "sessions": null,
          "page_views": null,
          "bounce_rate": null
        }
      },
      {
        "region_id": 36,
        "region_name": "Midwest",
        "data": {
          "ga_site_id": null,
          "goal_completions": null,
          "users": null,
          "sessions": null,
          "page_views": null,
          "bounce_rate": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What technology / language are you using?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, that's an HTTP response with a JSON body. What is doing the returning? The only thing I can think of is doing `return response.results`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. You are showing a full repsonse including header information.  YOu are saying nothing about how you are trying to work with the JSON data (do you just want to extract get date under results property?) or create the JSON (do you want to create the JSON differently so as to not have `meta` node?)  Is you question focused on how to create the JSON data structure or how to work with the data structure you have? Or do you just have access to the the raw HTTP responses and are trying to figure out how to separate header information from content?

Comment: this is a return value from a curl response.. it was returned as a string..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use cURL to get jSON data and decode the data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700960/how-to-use-curl-to-get-json-data-and-decode-the-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in `PHP` you want to use the `json_decode()` function on your output like this:

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode($response);
$onlyResults = $jsonDecode->results;
```

which you can then use to gather or loop through the rest of the object.

and I'd suggest turning off CURL response headers:

`set CURLOPT_HEADER to false.`

Comment: this is a return value from a curl response.. it was returned as a string

Comment: what language are you using to parse the curl response?

Comment: this was in php too.

Comment: check answer again :) fixed it accordingly