# Atemping to use cURL to parse JSON -- var_dump returning NULL

Tags: php, json, curl

I am attempting to parse the JSON from the URL bellow. However when I run the `var_dump(json_decode($result, true))` it returns NULL. But when I copy the URL from the `echo $item_url`  it returns the proper JSON.

Another issue I have read is the `var_dump(json_decode($result, true));` is returning a string with spaces and that could be an issue

```
$item_url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=" . $rgDescriptions->market_hash_name;

echo $item_url;

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($item_url));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Bellow is an example of a URL that may get passed.

http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20|%20Aquamarine%20Revenge%20(Minimal%20Wear)

Comment: Check this answer to similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700960/how-to-use-curl-to-get-json-data-and-decode-the-data

Comment: Here 2nd parameter may be issue; try this var_dump(json_decode($result));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working for me after changing a line in your code. I think you need to encode `$rgDescriptions->market_hash_name` only not whole url.

Change

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($item_url));
```

**TO**

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $item_url);
```

**Full Code**

```
$item_url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20|%20Aquamarine%20Revenge%20(Minimal%20Wear)";

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $item_url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

**Output:**

```
array(4) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["lowest_price"]=>
  string(6) "$26.38"
  ["volume"]=>
  string(3) "133"
  ["median_price"]=>
  string(6) "$26.35"
}
```

Comment: You are right, I needed to encode '$rgDescriptions->market_hash_name' not the whole URL. Thanks a bunch.