# Can't use cURL returned data?

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm using cURL to query a minecraft server so I can display certain information about the server.

code:

```
$url = URL . '/api.php';
$params= 'case=getinfo';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$gameinfo = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($gameinfo);
```

If I dump the returned data I get:

```
string(264) """{"hostname":"A Minecraft Server","gametype":"SMP","game_id":"MINECRAFT","version":"1.9","plugins":"CraftBukkit on Bukkit 1.9-R0.1-SNAPSHOT: PlayerData 1.0","map":"world","numplayers":"0","maxplayers":"200","hostport":"25565","hostip":"192.168.1.20","players":[]}"
```

I've tried using the the data in the following ways:

```
echo $gameinfo["hostname"];
echo $gameinfo->hostname;
echo $gameinfo[0]["hostname"];
echo $gameinfo[0]->hostname;
using foreach($gameinfo as $info)
```

for each of those I either get illegal string or non-object

So how can I use?

Comment: Dont you need to json_decode($gameinfo); before you read it?

Comment: I've tried that as well, didn't work. It turns the whole thing to null.

Comment: you get a string not an object from curl so you need to make it an object first before you can access key-value pairs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use cURL to get jSON data and decode the data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700960/how-to-use-curl-to-get-json-data-and-decode-the-data)

Comment: @scrappedcola So how would I convert it to an object?

Comment: If the JSON is bad, json_decode will return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your response is JSON which you need PHP to decode first before you use it as an array. Also trim the quotes off

```
$gameinfo = curl_exec($ch);
$gameinfo = json_decode(trim($gameinfo, '"'), true);

var_dump($gameinfo);
```