# GET a JSON Array with an API in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

Basically I'm trying to GET an API that gives me a JSON array. It should only be one integer. Whenever I try to though I receive the error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /public_html/call.php on line 16
```

Here's call.php:

```
    <?php
require 'connection.php';

$players2weeks = '(removed api)';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $players2weeks);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($response);

print_r($response);
echo $response->players_2weeks;
?>
```

I have the print_r for troubleshooting but I'm getting nothing. My apologies for a noob question by the way, I have no experience with JSON.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: first print your json response.

Comment: Please try
`$response = json_decode($response,true);
print_r($response);
echo $response['players_2weeks'];`

Comment: Try `$response['players_2weeks']` Because you decoded the json object.

Comment: I think its will return an array not object. Paste your `JSON` response first.

Comment: Thank you @ArshadShaikh. I'm no longer getting that error. If I want to use the result of the query in a formula, how would I do that? I'm being told I'm using a non-numeric value.

Comment: @Narayan When I remove the decode and print_r I get this:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'players_2weeks' in /public_html/call.php on line 14

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /public_html/call.php on line 14

Comment: Yes, of course, you change your second variable name as `$respons1` or something.

Comment: @Nawin Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: `$players2weeks = '(removed api)';`  What is mean this?

Comment: I'm just hiding the API. Perhaps this will help:

/api.php?r=players_2weeks

Comment: Please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701318/4511459

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this Code :

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$players2weeks = '(removed api)';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $players2weeks);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$responses = json_decode($response);

print_r($responses);
echo $responses['players_2weeks'];
?>
```

You should change the format of echo when the decoded JSON objects. and the Variable same means some clashes in the print so I changed the `$response` variable also...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, still not receiving any input and it isn't working in a formula. Here's my formula code:
require 'call.php';

$player2weeks_result = $responses;
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

$formula = ($player2weeks_result-($player2weeks_result*$a))-(($player2weeks_result-($player2weeks_result*$a))*$b);

echo $formula;

Comment: Change to your `$player2weeks_result = $responses` to this `$player2weeks_result = $responses['players_2weeks']`

Comment: What is the result you get when print `echo $responses['players_2weeks'];` this?

Comment: please post your JSON print

Comment: print_r($player2weeks_result) doesn't show anything

Comment: Am  telling `print_r($responses);`

Comment: That also returns nothing. I think it might be an API problem. Is there a good way to confirm?

Answer (score -1):

You have to make array to json string by using the  json_encode() function on the api.

For example: xxx.php (api)

$result = array(); //return array
echo json_encode($result);

Then you can get result by json array on the api caller.

```
var_dump(json_decode($result));           // Object
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));     // Associative array
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my API. The API just tells me it returns results in JSON array.

Comment: If you are accessing HTTPS URLs and you do not receive any contents, try to disable verifying SSL.

Comment: <?php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
?>

Comment: I've added those options and it's giving me an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: the 500 Internal Server Error is a server-side error, meaning the problem probably isn't with your computer or internet connection but instead is a problem with the website's server.