# Unable to fetch single data from JSON Curl Output in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a code which should fetch courseID from JSON response obtained , But currently it is not fetching anything . It shows me the entire response and not one . can someone help me with this .

JSON response obtained.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "CourseID": "ASPO",
      "Success": "Yes"
    }
  ]
}
```

i just want to retrieve the CourseID.

and below is my code

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://AbC:3939');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ABC=AE");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer hjhjhjhjhjhj338sj';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);


if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch) ;
}else{
    $result_value = json_decode($result);
   print_r($result_value->results[0]->CourseID);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: You're ignoring the `results` key.

Comment: results ? @ÁlvaroGonzález, even if i give $result[0]-> CourseID, it is not working

Comment: $result_value->results[0]->CourseID

Comment: Side note, `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` doesn't make any sense when decoding.

Comment: Don't confuse JSON data with your local variable names.

Comment: still am not getting single CourseID, it just prints the whole JSON value @Loïc

Comment: `json_decode($result,true)` returns an associative _array_, use array notation

Comment: I updated the code , Can you just have a look @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: It should work now as is…

Comment: I have posted my entire CURL PHP file , can anyone please check as am not getting the result you guys are saying @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: What result *are* you getting?!

Comment: You're missing [`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701318/476)…?

Comment: I gave that and it’s the same ,  am getting that Jason response but what I want is a single value which is course Id @deceze

Comment: You're missing [`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701318/476).

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this answers the original question (extract information from JSON response).*

The top level element in your JSON string is an object with a single `results` key that holds everything. You aren't referencing such key anywhere in your code.

The name of the local PHP variable where you store the results is irrelevant, there isn't any automatic behaviour linked to that.

If you use [json_decode()](https://php.net/json_decode) with the `$associative` flag you get JSON objects converted to PHP arrays (JSON arrays become PHP arrays no matter the flags). If unsure, just inspect your data with either a step debugger or e.g. `var_dump($result_value)`:

```
array(1) {
  'results' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
      'CourseID' =>
      string(4) "ASPO"
      'Success' =>
      string(3) "Yes"
    }
  }
}
```

In php you can access array elements by specifying the key inside square brackets so:

```
var_dump($result_value['results'][0]['CourseID'], $result_value['results'][0]['Success']);
```

```
string(4) "ASPO"
string(3) "Yes"
```

Comment: Kindly check the entire question, i have posted the entire CURL PHP file. Since am not getting what you guys said .

Comment: I think you've made it a different question (how to get response body using Curl). You are neither capturing Curl response nor returning it with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`.

Comment: got it . That was the reason

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with your shared result and got the COURSEID.

```
$resp = '{
  "results": [
    {
      "CourseID": "ASPO",
      "Success": "Yes"
    }
  ]
}';


$res = json_decode($resp);

print_r($res->results[0]->CourseID);
```

Comment: This works, but when i do the same thing in my code it just don't return anything

Comment: $result_value = json_decode($result, true);
   print_r($result_value);
Could you please change a little in print result like above, and share the result ?

Comment: Yup sure, just a min

Comment: {"results":[{"CourseID":"ASPO","Success":"True"}]}1

Comment: Please try this: 
$result = // store your result in var $result i.e. '{"results":[{"CourseID":"ASPO","Success":"True"}]}';

$res = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($res['results'][0]['CourseID']);

Comment: one second, will update you

Comment: am still getting the entire JSON value as Result ->{"results":[{"CourseID":"ASPO","Success":"True"}]}

Comment: Please share what you are trying with output in all stages?

Comment: i just want to get the value of CourseID as output. That's it

Comment: just want to check if courseID is ASPO, and allot some values to variable

Comment: Are you sure your output is {"results":[{"CourseID":"ASPO","Success":"True"}]} when you print $result_value = json_decode($result, true); print_r($result_value);
Because it should give an array.

Comment: yeah , it is showing the same output

Comment: {"results":[{"reCourseID":"ASPO","Success":"True"}]}1

Comment: json_decode function should give an array but in your case it prints json, strange.
And one more thing, what is 1 in the end of json output?