# how to read json from the given link

Tags: php, json

I'm using an API which returns a JSON.
here is the link to JSON http://getpincodes.info/api.php?pincode=421305
this is oupput json of above link
[{"pincode":"421305","city":"Vidyashram","district":"Thane","state":"MAHARASHTRA"}]
here is my code to read data:

```
  $json = file_get_contents("http://getpincodes.info/aenter code herepi.php?pincode=$zip");
$data=json_decode($json);
$city = $data->city;
echo $city; 
enter code here
```

i m getting the error while doing so
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place for just posting generic questions with no attempts of solving the problems yourself. This is borderline spam as well.

Comment: I tried with the code  $json = file_get_contents('http://getpincodes.info/api.php?pincode=421305');
$data=json_decode($json);

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to write better questions and hopefully get better help.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working". What errors do you get? What are you doing? What do you expect to see? What do you actually see?

Comment: the above link gives city,district and state

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url

Comment: i want to retrive those data

Comment: $json = file_get_contents('http://getpincodes.info/api.php?pincode=$zip');
$data=json_decode($json);
$city = $data->city;

Comment: You know you can edit questions right?

Comment: i am getting this error:Notice : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You need to use double quotes for the file get contents if you are trying to give $zip like that.

Comment: i tried with double quotes but its not working.

Comment: Why wouldn't you put that in the original question? You should ask: "I am trying to do x, here is my code: {code}. I get the following error: {error}, but I expect Y." Then you would have got an answer straight away.

Comment: and i m new to stackoverflow so sorry if made any mistake

Comment: The how to ask document explains this all as does the document that you ticked "I have read" when you signed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be receiving an array of results instead of a naked object. So

```
$city = $data->city; // does not work: $data is an array
```

but

```
$city = $data[0]->city; // should work: $data[0] is an object with a city key
```