# How to access the name of someone with messenger chat bot? (Facebook Messenger SDK)

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence, facebook-chatbot

Hi I'm very new to coding in PHP and Messenger Bots.

I was wondering how i would access the name of someone who was messaging my chat bot.

Comment: Have you considered accepting any answer here? Have any one of them answered your question?

Answer (score 7):

The [User Profile API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile) may help you.

use the `event.sender.id` received from the messenger bot server (/webhook), and follow the request below

> ```
> curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
> ```

then you could get the returned json below

```
{
     "first_name": "Peter",
     "last_name": "Chang",
     "profile_pic": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13055603_10105219398495383_8237637584159975445_n.jpg?oh=1d241d4b6d4dac50eaf9bb73288ea192&oe=57AF5C03&__gda__=1470213755_ab17c8c8e3a0a447fed3f272fa2179ce",
     "locale": "en_US",
     "timezone": -7,
     "gender": "male"
}
```

Comment: So i just paste the curl thing into the php code right?
how do i access the returned json?
(i.e. i want to say "hello" + <name of the person>)

Comment: see how to make a http get request and access the returned json in php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url

Comment: Which permissions should I active?

Comment: @enriquo you don't need further permissions, you just need PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, please see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below PHP snippet to get name of the user

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?fields=first_name,last_name&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo 'Hi ' . $obj['first_name'] . ' ' . $obj['last_name']
```

Comment: Sorry I've never actually used PHP. How am I supposed to use your PHP snippet(i.e. where do i put it in the code)?

I have the code that i tried based off yours in a comment below.

Comment: if($messageText == "hi" ) {
    //$answer = "Hello" ;
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?fields=first_name,last_name&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
$answer =  'Hi ' . $obj['first_name'] . ' ' . $obj['last_name'];
}

else if ($messageText != "") {
    $answer = "Sorry I dont think I understand what you said. Try asking me something else!";
}

Comment: @RayyaanMustafa, you have to paste this code where you are processing the message text.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajesh Hedge

Your code have a small error:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?fields=first_name,last_name&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result); // *** here
echo 'Hi ' . $obj['first_name'] . ' ' . $obj['last_name']

$obj = json_decode($result, **true**);
```

`$result` need to be converted into associative array before you can access it like this: `$obj['first_name']`

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for details.