# How to get JSON parameter from URL

Tags: php, json, curl

Hello I'm coming from [Get JSON object from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url)

I tried to get marketCap->usd.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://coinmarketcap.northpole.ro/api/v5/ZCL.json');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $result->marketCap->usd;
```

Comment: throw a print statement in there above your echo call to see what your json decoded object looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Change `echo $result->marketCap->usd;` for `echo $obj->marketCap->usd;`

You have saved the data decoded in `$obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Last line of your code should be

```
echo $obj->marketCap->usd;
```