# Extracting "image_url" value and display as image src

Tags: php

Is it possible to extract the value of "image_url" from this link

http://theapache64.xyz:8080/gpix/v1/gpix?keyword=honda%20civic%202009&limit=1

and display as `<img src="">` using php?

Comment: Yes, Download the result of the Link as a string, looks like its giving a JSON . so then access the JSON array "images" and get the "image_url" property.

Comment: @cwishva thanks will try that

Comment: take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch data from json as follow

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://theapache64.xyz:8080/gpix/v1/gpix?keyword=honda%20civic%202009&limit=1');

$arr = json_decode($content,true);

$url = $arr['data']['images'][0]['image_url'];

echo "<img src='".$url."'>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found a solution.

I will also post my solution here just in case other will encounter the same problem

```
    <?php

$json_file = file_get_contents('http://theapache64.xyz:8080/gpix/v1/gpix?keyword='.$combineurl.'&limit=1');

$jfo = json_decode($json_file);


$posts = $jfo->data->images;



foreach ($posts as $post) {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $post->image_url; ?>" alt="" width="500">
    <?php
}
?>
```