# AJAX value sending error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I have problems with the script below. The problem I think lies on data that need to be sent to php via AJAX.

jQuery

```
$('.send').live("click", function(){

    $.ajax({

        url:'foobar.php',
        type:'post',
        data: 'id=' + $(this).attr('id'),
        dataType:'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data) {

            switch (data.status)
            {
                case "a":

                    alert(data.text);

                    break;

                case "b":

                    alert(data.text);

                    break;

                }
            },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert ("error: "+textStatus);

            }
        })
    }
```

and, PHP

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

switch ($id) {

    case "foo":

        $data["status"] = "a";
        $data["text"] = "foo-foo";
        echo json_encode($data);

        break;

    case "bar":

        $data["status"] = "b";
        $data["text"] = "bar-bar";
        echo json_encode($data);

        break;

    }
```

but, if I do this

```
//data: 'id=' + $(this).attr('id'),
```

and change this

```
$id = 'foo';
```

the script work just fine. What I need to do to make both script above can work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: alert $(this).attr('id') then see what comes

Comment: what is the HTML that you are using to post?

Comment: can you check alert($(this).attr('id')) is 'undefined'?Or can you show the element with class "send"

Comment: live is deprecated try to use on .and for your problem use firebug and check console for post data and response .. Thanks

Comment: @shin yes it's alerted, and the html object is a parapgraph <p>

Comment: This the mark up: <p id="foo" class="send">Click This!</p>

Comment: Remove the `ContentType` line in your AJAX. You are **not** sending a JSON data, you are sending a plain percentile encoded data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will put my comment as an answer.

Apart from using a deprecated jQuery API, what others didn't point out is the following:

What you are doing in the below line:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

is that you are promising the server that the HTTP entity will be a JSON-string, which is not the case. It is actually the usual percentile-encoded string. (`a=b&c=d&e=f`).

If you remove that line, the browser sends a default value Content-Type as `application/x-www-url-form-encoded`. That would trigger PHP to parse the HTTP entity as such and give you as the `$_REQUEST` array properly populated.

Comment: It make sense now, thank you very much.. this solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
data: 'id=' + $(this).attr('id'),
```

to

```
data: {id :  $(this).attr('id')},
```

also use `on` here, `live` is deprecated

```
$('.send').on("click", function(){
```

Comment: @Yogesy Suthar I've been try this solution but the code still not working, BTW I use the latest version of jQuery and PHP..

Answer (score 0):

You need to JSON encode the data being sent.

It should look something like: '{"id":"' + $(this).attr('id') + '"}'

Comment: No need for all those additional quotes; `{id: $(this).attr('id')}`

Comment: I have changed the code to what you've told but still get parsererror

Comment: Well you might need to decoded the JSON string on the server side, such as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ,

```
     $('.send').click(function(){
```

Insted of

```
  $('.send').live("click", function(){
```

There is an error showing

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'(live is deprecated)

Comment: I've try this solution with same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues present in the code in the question.

Don't use `.live()`. It was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed entirely in jQuery 1.9 (the latest release version). Instead, use `.on()`:

```
$('.send').on('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

Or, if you actually need the event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.send', function() {
    ...
});
```

When setting the `data` property in your object literal passed as an argument of `$.ajax()`, you have two options: a string or an object literal. So either:

```
data: {id: this.id},
```

or

```
data: 'id=' + this.id,
```

Note that I'm using `this.id`, not `$(this).attr('id');`. Why? Because it avoids unnecessary usage of jQuery, and because `.attr()` isn't the correct function - you want the `id` property, so you should use `.prop()` (though, again, don't use jQuery unless you need to).

Finally, you haven't closed the call to `.click()`, so you need to add a `);` to the end of your posted code.

The entire thing should look something like this:

```
$('.send').on("click", function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: 'foobar.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'id=' + this.id,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {

            switch (data.status) {
            case "a":

                alert(data.text);

                break;

            case "b":

                alert(data.text);

                break;

            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert("error: " + textStatus);

        }
    })
});
```