# Parsing JSON array getting name of array

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON file.

```
{
  "2438": {
    "open": false,
    "tag": "borci1",
  },
  "2210": {
    "open": false,
    "tag": "Jeskinky",
  },
}
```

I know how to get eg. "tag" or "open", but how can I get "2438" and "2210" ?

Comment: `$arr['2438']` isn't it?

Comment: Can this answer help you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php

Comment: Just spend some time on php.net... in particular the pages that deal with loops and browse the list of [array functions in php](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), 79 functions in total, there's bound to be one in there that deals with `array_keys`. After that, please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), to understand why this isn't a good SO question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after parsing json with `json_decode` use foreach

```
foreach($json as $key=>$value)
{
//$key is the index of array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_arr=json_decode($string,true);
print_r( array_keys($json_arr) );
```