# How to extract value from a below json using php

Tags: php, json

Below is the starting of json that I've received in $json variable.

```
{"page":"0","cartaddonpopover":{"refreshfeature":1,"featurehtml":""},"initiateid":null,"containsmapitem":0,"wishlist":{"refreshfeature":1,"featurehtml":"\n<div id=\"cart-wishlist\" style=\"display:none;\" class=\"cart-wish-list\"  >\n</div>\n\n"},"gutter":{"refreshfeature":1,"featurehtml":"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div id=\"cart-gutter\" class=cart-gutter quantity=\"151\">\n\n
```

I want to extract the value of `quantity`, which is `151` in above case.

I'm currently using, `$quantity = $json->featurehtml->{"cart-gutter"}->quantity;` and I know that I'm wrong. Please guide.

Comment: Can you post `print_r($json);` ?

Comment: Will the json always be exactly of the same structure? If so, `json_decode` and some Regex should help you.

Comment: @TheWolf : yes. The json will always be in same structure. Please suggest some answer.

Comment: use json_decode() and then post the result here. I thin json_decode will help

Comment: A Google for "php decode json" provides 5 helpful hits directly at the beginning... additionally, there are several answers about this on SO

Comment: Do you create this json, or is it from an api you cant edit? Because fixing the api would be a lot better than regex

Comment: ok.. lemme post the json_decode()

Comment: quantity isn't the value of a JSON component, it's an attribute of an HTML element that's in the `featurehtml` property. You need to use an HTML DOM Parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP- Decode JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609354/php-decode-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a regexp to do this.

```
preg_match('/quantity=\\\"(\d+)\\\"/', $json, $matches);
$quantity = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$html = str_get_html(json_decode($json)->featurehtml);
$quantity = $html->find("#cart-gutter")->quantity;
```

Comment: hey, str_get_html is not working in my case. Can you suggest any alternate ?

Comment: There are a number of ways to process HTML in PHP, but I'm not really familiar with them. They're in the Programming PHP book.

Comment: For $html = str_get_html($json->featurehtml); , I'm getting, Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: I assumed that `$json` was the result of calling `json_decode()` on that JSON string. Was I wrong?

Comment: No. I didn't decoded the json. The json i presented was encoded.

Comment: If you didn't decode it, why did you have `$json->featurehtml` in the question? Anyway, I added the call to json_decode to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['quantity'];
```

Comment: Take a closer look at his JSON. Quantity is not a property, it's an attribute of an HTML element.