# Use JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I use some website that give me information about IP but the information that that website return in JSON and I don't know the JSON. I want to use this to check the user if it is from IR do something but I dont know how to use JSON in php,
Here is the JSON that the website return:

```
{"address":"0.0.0.0.0","country":"IR","stateprov":"somewhere ","city":"Tehr\somewhere (somewhere)"}
```

I want to save the country in a variable and add this code to my website:

```
<?php
if($country == 'IR'){
//Do somethong  
}
```

`$country` is the country name that return from the website,

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Did you even try to google it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP- Decode JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609354/php-decode-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use `json_decode()`.

```
$s = '{"address":"0.0.0.0.0","country":"IR","stateprov":"somewhere ","city":"Tehrsomewhere (somewhere)"}';

$d = json_decode($s);
```

Which returns:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [address] => 0.0.0.0.0
    [country] => IR
    [stateprov] => somewhere 
    [city] => Tehrsomewhere (somewhere)
)
```

That would allow you to check the country/other fields like this:

```
if($d->country == 'IR') {
    // do something
}
```

**NOTE:** you had an error (invalid json) in your `"city"` field, the `\` makes it invalid.

[<kbd>**Example**</kbd>](https://eval.in/172579)

---

You can ensure that your json is valid by checking it at [**`JSON Lint`**](http://jsonlint.org/).

Comment: A question How can I use [country] in my php if?

Comment: @King_Far Look at updated answer. You'd use `$d->country` from my example I posted. (*using it as an object, not as an array*)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the function `json_decode`.It decodes the `JSON string`

[See the documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would like to inform you that given json is not valid. `"city" : "Tehr\somewhere (somewhere)"` is not valid because of `"\"`.

So change it into below given format.

```
$jsonEncode = { "address": "0.0.0.0.0","country": "IR","stateprov": "somewhere ","city": "There somewhere (somewhere)"}

$jsonDecode = json_decode($jsonEncode,true);
```

Now you will get the value in array format.

```
Array(
    [address] => 0.0.0.0.0
    [country] => IR
    [stateprov] => somewhere 
    [city] => There somewhere (somewhere)

);
```

`print_r($jsonDecode['city']);` will give you city name or details

Answer (score 0):

You have to first decode this json string.

```
$data = '{"address":"0.0.0.0.0","country":"IR","stateprov":"somewhere ","city":"Tehr\somewhere (somewhere)"}';

$decodeData = json_decode($data);
```

Then use this decode json string in php like this.

```
if($decodeData->country == 'IR'){
//Do somethong  
}
```

Comment: And what's the difference in your and @Darrens answer? Except the variable names?