# How to receive json via POST in PHP using JsonObjectRequest in Android

Tags: php, android, json, jsonobjectrequest

I am new to PHP.

I am sending **json** using JsonObjectRequest in Android via POST Method.

I don't know how to retrieve that json in php and decode it. Could you help me?
The json I am sending is

```
{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test"}
```

I need both the JSON objects in seperate variables.

Comment: Try `json_decode('{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test"}');`

Comment: json_decode function will help you [json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP- Decode JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609354/php-decode-json)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this data by `file_get_contents("php://input");`. And then decode it by `json_decode()`. Try following code:

```
$data_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data_json,true);
var_dump($data); //show your data
```

**EDIT**

To echo your data:

```
echo $data['firstname'];
echo $data['lastname'];
```

Comment: How to get both of the json objects in seperate variables and echo them?

Comment: store them in variable like `$firstname = $data['firstname'];`