# splitting apart response from an API

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to start using APIs, doing calls and so forth.  Just barely starting to learn.  Found a way to get Facebook shares on a post using the graph api.

I did this with PHP; here is the code:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/? id=mydomain.com');

echo $response;
```

this is the response that I get:

```
{"id":"http://sportsmockery.com/2014/11/hey-bears-fire-everyone/","shares":22}
```

What I want is to somehow get the share count (22) into a variable so I can do stuff with it…(i changed the domain that gets that share count to my domain.com);

anyway; I am not sure what is the standard way to do this, if you control what is received with how you do your call; or if you just get the full response and pull out what you want…

Been looking around and have not been able to find anything that will really help with this.

I am hoping someone can help me with this…

All the best,  G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which will make all of the properties easily accessible.

```
$parsedResponse = json_decode($response);
$count = $parsedResponse->shares;

echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a json response.

[Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php