# How can I parse this JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, parsing, decode

How can I parse [this JSON](http://steamcommunity.com/id/Mitch8910/inventory/json/440/2/), which is supposed to display the items a user has in their Steam inventory.

I have tried this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/Mitch8910/inventory/json/440/2/');
$json = json_decode($data);
echo $data;
```

It returns the same as just visiting the link. I can't get anything like this to work either:

```
$id = $json->type;
echo $type;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Comment: After `json_decode` you will get an array, not a object. Use `$json['type']`

Comment: @mcklayin json_decode will return object array by default.

Comment: @ Kamran Adil You are right  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to get type

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/Mitch8910/inventory/json/440/2/');
$json = json_decode($data);

 foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
{
    echo $mydata->type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/Mitch8910/inventory/json/440/2/');
$json = json_decode($data);
echo $data;
```

you are echoing $data that is your input (so you see the same as opening the link directly). To see if the json_decode is working fine you should print $json.
So instead of

```
echo $data;
```

use

```
echo '<pre>'
print_r($json);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/Mitch8910/inventory/json/440/2/');
$json = json_decode($data);
```

Now $json has 2 objects.

you can access like.

```
$json->rgInventory;
$json->success;
```

if you want to fetch all data from $json->rgInventory;

```
foreach($json->rgInventory as $e){
    //var_dump($e);
    echo $e->id;
    echo $e->classid;
    echo $e->instanceid; 
}
```

etc.