# json response handling issue

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm stuck with retrieving json response below is the json output. Your help would be highly appreciated.

```
{ "productHeader" : { "totalHits" : 684 }, "products" : [ { "name" : "Victoria Hotels", "productImage" : { "url" : "http://hotels.com/hotels/9000000/8640000/8633700/8633672/8633672_20_b.jpg" }, "language" : "en", "description" : "Location. Victoria Hotels is in Foshan (Nanhai) and area attractions include Renshou Temple and New Plaza Stadium. Additional regional attractions include Guangdong Folk Art Museum and Bright Filial Piety Temple.", "identifiers" : { }, "fields" : [ { "name" : "regions2", "value" : "Guangdong" },
```

Please help me to  fetch the particular values. For example if I need to fetch the name, image url from the json response.

Comment: Use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) to get an array and then just access the keys.

Comment: In php you can use json_decode to obtain an array structure from a json

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) to parse a JSON string to an array and access it's values:

```
// assuming, that $string contains the json response
// second parameter to true, to get an array instead of an object
$data = json_decode( $string, true );
if ( $data ) {
  echo $data['products'][0]['name'];
  // or whatever value
} else {
  echo 'JSON could not be parsed, error: ' . json_last_error();
}
```

To show all values in the products array, simple loop it:

```
if ( $data ) {
  foreach($data['products'] as $product){
      echo $product['name'];
  }
  // or whatever value
} else {...
```

Comment: `products` is a sibling of `productHeader`, not a child

Comment: @Steve can you please specify the syntax for that  ,I am totally stuck here

Comment: @StupidDojo as per the above code, but you need to select the 1st item in the array, so: `echo $data['products'][0]['name'];`

Comment: @Steve thanks its shows the values , but if i want to display the result in a loop how I am gonna do that .

Comment: @StupidDojo Made an edit to show a loop, Hope thats OK Florian

Comment: @Steve Sure :) I thought about to add this, too, but i was unsure if that would be helpful, so no worries and  thanks for adding it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use PHP to get the values, check this:

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($decodedJson);
```

You will get an array, to get image source and other tags you need to do it in a loop or select concrete index like:

```
echo $decodedJson['productHeader']['products'][0]['productImage']['url'];
```

In JS you should extract the values the same way.

Comment: sorry it still not fetching the .