# How to parse url response?

Tags: php, parsing, curl, response

I got response from URL like this. I want value of `sid`. How can I get this?

```
{"response": "success","body":{ "sid" : "5f255c86a", "role" : "user" }}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above response looks to b `JSON` so you can use `json_decode()`function.

Try

```
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($response);

echo $json->body->sid;
```

**Note** You need to replace `$url` with URL of response page.

Answer (score 2):

It JSON format so use `json_decode()` function.

```
$response = json_decode($response);

echo $response->body->sid;
```

or

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
echo $response['body']['sid'];
```

If you pass second argument as true then it will return associative array.