# Using preg_match when pattern is an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Basically i'm storing 2 files into 2 differents array. The first one is my pattern and the second one is my "subject".

```
<?php 

$file1 = fopen('file1.txt', 'r+');
$file2 = fopen('file2.geojson', 'r+');

while(!feof($file1)){

    $buffer = fgets($file1);
    $tab[] = $buffer;
}

while(!feof($file2)){
    $buffer2 = fgets($file2);
    $tab2[] = $buffer2;

}


for($j=0; $j<count($tab2);$j++){
  for($i=0; $i<count($tab);$i++){
    if(preg_match("#\"$tab[$i]\"#", $tab2[$j])){
        echo "Found ! <br>";
        echo $tab2[$j] . "<br>";        
    }
  }
}

fclose($file1);
fclose($file2);

?>
```

The problem is only the last item in 'tab' is evaluated. I guess my regex is not well written.

File1 contains zip code on each line :

```html
67810
67207
67980
67300
67204
67112
67117
67800
67203
```

The second file is geojson and contains all the geoshapes of France cities. Here is a small example :

```html
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
                                                                                
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "26140", "LIB": "Saint-Rambert-d'Albon", "DEP": "26", "SURF": 82.710226, "POP2010": 12812.000000, "_COL6": 5148.082000 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 4.910952316875446, 45.239468880779881 ], [ 4.927807974060221, 45.236053935360097 ], [ 4.923509798950193, 45.238217934615989 ], [ 4.910952316875446, 45.233371738069984 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "26150", "LIB": "Die", "DEP": "26", "SURF": 315.349961, "POP2010": 6301.000000, "_COL6": 3011.687900 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 5.429793245468118, 44.703247891503587 ], [ 5.413013470624613, 44.688042393782084 ], [ 5.394637223225049, 44.687622044498482 ], [ 5.400643279242749, 44.678358831586564 ], [ 5.453052724102394, 44.704914679294212 ], [ 5.437312497288061, 44.700146412514492 ], [ 5.429793245468118, 44.703247891503587 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "26160", "LIB": "La Begude-de-Mazenc", "DEP": "26", "SURF": 181.940199, "POP2010": 7285.000000, "_COL6": 3040.837200 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 5.04538870963719, 44.610308524697103 ], [ 5.038809331299684, 44.59757761860763 ], [ 5.051232557215011, 44.603003224683015 ], [ 5.07330477638073, 44.59956580435167 ], [ 5.077375187960177, 44.592032286541126 ], [ 5.06659791007967, 44.584741592759165 ], [ 5.062893239233112, 44.56374699945075 ], [ 5.049501218954479, 44.557440600925943 ], [ 5.04538870963719, 44.559705577318169 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

My goal is : each time i recognize zip code of file1 in file2, i copy the current line and write in a new geojson file. Maybe there are better ways for doing that ?

Comment: If you try to parse JSON with regex, your suspicion is most probably correct.

Comment: Yes i'm almost sure it comes from here :/ How can i do that properly then ?

Comment: You would need to show example data from each file.

Comment: `"#\"" . preg_quote($tab[$i], '#') . "\"#"`

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. A basic example of using JSON in PHP: `$string = file_get_contents("/home/michael/test.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($json_a as $person_name => $person_a) {
    echo $person_a['status'];
}`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343664/3832970).

Comment: I've edit my post sorry. So thanks to json array, i can compare my values properly ?