# Storing Numeric Data using AJAX POST Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to store numeric data (integers) using a simple AJAX request:

```
function sendRating(rating) {
    var userRating = rating.value;
    $.ajax({
          url: '/rating',
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify({
              "rating": userRating
          }),
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: (...)
    });
}
```

This function is attached to buttons that have values (1,2,3,4,5). Because I'm using `JSON.stringify`, the numbers get converted to a string when I check the records in the database. When I return the results in the database, they look like this: `{ "rating": "4" }`

How can I avoid this?

Comment: If I got your point this may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thanks for the link but I'm not using PHP. Bascially what I'm trying to do is that the database should return the 4 without "quotes". Like this: `{"rating":4}`

Comment: @mapr "The database" is server side, which has nothing to do with the data you're *sending*, and we couldn't help with your back end anyway since you provide zero information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form values are strings. You're *telling* it to send a string.

`JSON.stringify` doesn't convert numbers to strings (and running it in the console to test your assumptions would show that immediately).

There are many options, but here's one of them:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
  rating: parseInt(userRating, 10)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps. I did not know that `values` are string, but knew the problem was somewhere on the client side. That's why I did not talk too much about the server side.