# Entering JSON data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to get JSON data and enter it into my database.

Here's my current code:

```
while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $domain = $row["domain"];
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = "https://www.example.com/";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "apikey=123&test=$domain");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);
    print $output;

    // CODE SHOULD BE ADDED HERE I THINK

    curl_close ($ch);

    $sql_to_update = "UPDATE monitoring SET socials='$socials', update_time='$time' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql_to_update);
}
```

Here's an example of the JSON results I'm getting:

```
{
   "resource":"random data",
   "tests":100,
   "total":250,
   "networks":{
      "FaceBook":{
         "detected":true,
         "result":"ignore"
      },
      "Twitter Inc":{
         "detected":false,
         "result":"ignore"
      },
      "MySpace":{
         "detected":true,
         "result":"ignore"
      },
      "Pinterest":{
         "detected":true,
         "result":"ignore"
      },
      "Instagram":{
         "detected":false,
         "result":"ignore"
      }
   }
}
```

All that I need to do is get the `networks` that have `detected` set to `true` and insert them into my database using the variable `$socials`.

For example, for the JSON example listed above, I'd want the following entered into the `socials` column of the database:  `FaceBook, MySpace, Pinterest`

If there are no `networks` that have `detected` set to `true`, then I want to enter `NONE FOUND` into that column instead.

Anyone know how I can work with the JSON output to get this into my database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check the code to get the desired data that you want to update:-

<?php
$link = '{
   "resource":"random data",
   "tests":100,
   "total":250,
   "networks":{
      "FaceBook":{
         "detected":true,
         "result":"ignore"
      },
      "Twitter Inc":{
         "detected":false,
         "result":"ignore"
      },
      "MySpace":{
         "detected":true,
         "result":"ignore"
      },
      "Pinterest":{
         "detected":true,
         "result":"ignore"
      },
      "Instagram":{
         "detected":false,
         "result":"ignore"
      }
   }
}'; // suppose json variable is $link
$dataArr = json_decode($link);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($dataArr);// print the variable to see how json data looks when it converted to php array
$socials = '';
foreach($dataArr->networks as $key=>$dataA){
    if($dataA->detected == 1){
        $socials .= $key.',';
    }

}
$socials = trim($socials,',');
echo $socials;
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/506693

Now put your update code and that's it.

Comment: @user10848.Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make it an array for better handling `json_decode($json, true)`

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
echo '</pre>';
```

You'll get a stdClass object like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [resource] => random data
    [tests] => 100
    [total] => 250
    [networks] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FaceBook] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 1
                    [result] => ignore
                )

            [Twitter Inc] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => ignore
                )

            [MySpace] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 1
                    [result] => ignore
                )

            [Pinterest] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 1
                    [result] => ignore
                )

            [Instagram] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => ignore
                )

        )

)
```

then perform a loop on the array . I hope you know the rest . what should you do now.

Comment: Make it an array for better handling `json_decode($json, true)`