# retrieving json document property using php

Tags: php, json, couchbase

I have the following php logic that queries a couchbase database:

```
$myCluster = new CouchbaseCluster('couchbase://localhost');
$bucket = $myCluster->openBucket('reporting');
$result = $bucket->get('server_details_1');
$doc = $result->value;
var_dump($doc);
echo $doc->server_details->name."\n";
```

It's failing on the last line because I believe the way I'm trying to access the json object is incorrect. Perhaps it's no longer a json object... I'm not too sure.  But I do know that couchbase stores it as json in the database itself.

This is what the var_dump command returns which shows you the structure of the object:

```
string '{"server_details":{"name":"test_server","dns_name":"test.server.mydomain.net","ipv4":"10.1.16.106","ipv6":"","type":"primary"},"server_status":{"up_to_date":true},"packages":{"pack1":{"current_version":"x.x","previous_version":"x.x","last_updated_on":"2016-03-16","play_id":"link to audit table"},"pack2":{"current_version":"x.x","previous_version":"x.x","last_updated_on":"2016-03-16","play_id":"link to audit table"}}}' (length=438)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Comment: That's a valid json string but you have to get php to read it as an object to do what you want to do (json_decode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `json_decode` your data first, because when you get it from the server it is just a string.

```
$doc = json_decode($result->value);
echo $doc->server_details->name."\n";
```