# Read json steam inventory

Tags: php, api, steam

I'm currently reading someones inventory through

```
$inventory = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{$Steam64}/inventory/json/730/2");
```

this is analog to

```
file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetplayerSummaries/v0002/?key={$api}&steamids={$Steam64}");
```

here i get steamid64 with

```
{$steam->response->players[0]->personaname}
```

How to get a specific element in the inventory's `.json`? For example:

```
{"success":true,"rgInventory":{"5904013658":{"id":"5904013658","classid":"469437901","instanceid":"302028390","amount":"1","pos":1},"5903531561":{"id":"5903531561","classid":"1293508920","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":2},"5175566083":{"id":"5175566083","classid":"310780331","instanceid":"302028390","amount":"1","pos":3}
```

How to get classid? My solution above doesn't work for this :-(

aswell i need to read :

```
    pos":22}},"rgCurrency":[],"rgDescriptions":{"469437901_302028390":{"appid":"730","classid":"469437901","instanceid":"302028390","icon_url":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcV
```

The icon_url and other stuff in this part.

Greetings

Comment: Try to use `json_decode($response, true)` will convert associative array and you can work on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Comment: the problem is the 5904013658 or 469437901_302028390 i need them to get ids inside, but they change from user to user, they are not static, how do i fetch them?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your response is JSON try it as below:

```
$inventory = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{$Steam64}/inventory/json/730/2");
$response = json_decode($inventory, true);
```

This will return you Associative array which you can access easily. e.g. `$response['...']['...']`

Comment: thanks, that works for me, but the problem i have is the  rgDescriptions":{"469437901_302028390":{"appid":"730 or "rgInventory":{"5904013658":{"id":"5904013658" the numbers 469...390 and 590...658, how can i get them? I need them for fatching the classid, but they change from player to player. For example i use:                              $t = "469437901_302028390";

    $getitems = "{$inventory->rgDescriptions->$t->icon_url}";  but $t depends on the user and is always sometzhing else :/

Comment: please paste `vardump` of your `$response`

Comment: object(stdClass)#5 (6) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["rgInventory"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (22) { ["5904013658"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (5) { ["id"]=> string(10) "5904013658" ["classid"]=> string(9)                                      and  ["rgCurrency"]=> array(0) { } ["rgDescriptions"]=> object(stdClass)#29 (18) { ["469437901_302028390"]=> object(stdClass)#30 (20) { ["appid"]=> string(3) "730" ["classid"]=> string(9) "469437901" ["instanceid"]=> string(9) "302028390" ["icon_url"]=> string(199)