# PHP get JSON variables and add prefix

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I need to loop through some JSON and get the `Ids`

Here is my JSON

```
{"Master":123456,"Ids":[1,3,8]}
```

I need to get all of the `Ids` and add a prefix `.pre-` so I end up with this in PHP:

```
$Ids =  ".pre-1, .pre-3, .pre-8"
```

Any help with this is very much appreciated. I did look through other posts and tried some things but I couldn't do it.

Thanks

Comment: Lets see how you have tried to do this

Comment: I tried the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php?rq=1

Comment: Hint: [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), and then [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do these:

```
$json = '{"Master":123456,"Ids":[1,3,8]}';

$arr = json_decode($json);

$arr2 = array();
foreach($arr->Ids as $val){
    $arr2[] = ".pre-".$val;
}

echo $Ids = '"'.implode(", ", $arr2).'"'; //".pre-1, .pre-3, .pre-8"
```