# Php foreach json id create html

Tags: php, json

I'm new to php, so sorry about trivial question...

I have this JSON:

```
{"data":{"summary":{"records":67,"page":1,"total":67,"hasMore":0},"reservations":[{"id":1111111,"property":"villadianna","from":"2016-07-18","to":"2016-07-25"},"pricing":{"price":1164.2400,"currency":"EUR","retail":1323},"clientInfo":{"firstName":"pera","lastName":"peric","email":"myemail@gmail.com"},"status":1,"offline":0},{"id":222222,"property":"villadianna", etc. ... ...
```

How I can make foreach and create an table row for each reservation ID ?

now I have just:

```
echo $result;
```

Comment: Just decode it to an array.

Comment: please make an example

Comment: please google it and research it.

Comment: use json decode, var_dump(json_decode($json));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$json = json_decode($yourJson);
foreach ($json as $element) {
  print_r($element);
}
// In case you need to access a specific property
// $json->property
```

Each element will be an object.

You can use json_decode($yourJson, true); to get an array instead of the object.

More info here: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: please help to consctruct html as an table

Comment: Execute the code is pretty straightforward. You'll need a valid json string. You can access the reservations property directly. See the code. For the html table you can use some loops and the html <table> tag.

Comment: Please take a look at the code and the comments, it's there ;). You can use $json->reservations, and use loops.