# Parse a decoded json array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook-php-sdk

I have a decoded json array which I received from the facebook API:

```
$Myposts = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

When I printed $Myposts :

```
var_dump($Myposts);
```

It gived this :

```
    object(stdClass)[16]
  public 'data' => 
    array (size=24)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[12]
          public 'message' => string 'a mesagge..' (length=65)
          public 'created_time' => string '2016-09-18T16:41:10+0000' (length=24)
          public 'id' => string '111110037' (length=35)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[28]
          public 'message' => string 'How brave !' (length=11)
          public 'story' => string 'XXX shared Le XX video.' (length=59)
          public 'created_time' => string '2016-09-18T13:37:33+0000' (length=24)
          public 'id' => string '102172976' (length=35)

      23 => 
        object(stdClass)[50]
          public 'message' => string '...a message..' (length=259)
          public 'story' => string 'Bi added 3 new photos.' (length=33)
          public 'created_time' => string '2015-12-11T20:54:21+0000' (length=24)
          public 'id' => string '102191588' (length=35)
  public 'paging' => 
    object(stdClass)[51]
      public 'previous' => string 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/XXXX&__paging_token=YYYY&__previous=1' (length=372)
      public 'next' => string 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/XXX/feed?access_token=DDDD&limit=25&until=XXX&__paging_token=XXXX' (length=362)
```

I'm new to php, and I don't have any idea how to deal with this output, I would like to loop through all the messages and output the created_time of each message.

Any ideas ?

EDIT : I tried : `echo $myPosts['data'][message];` from [Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596), but I have had : "Undefined index: message". That's why I posted a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php

Comment: if you want to use these values than use loop.

Comment: I tried to use loop, but I didn't figured out how to extract the data array. 
I used thid : 
 `foreach ($aposts['data'] as $item)
 {
     echo "items:". $item['message'] ."\n";
 }` 
but got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `json_decode` turns the result into an associative array:

```
$myPosts = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

foreach ($myPosts['data'] as $post) {
    var_dump($post['message']);
}
```

Without using the second parameter the decoding returns objects:

```
$myPosts = json_decode($response->getBody());

foreach ($myPosts->data as $post) {
    var_dump($post->message);
}
```

Comment: I tested the first one, it works! but I don't know why I'm getting this error:  `Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\wamp64\www\ctest.php on line 131`
For the second one, I got this one : `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$message in C:\wamp64\www\ctest.php on line 138`

Comment: Maybe not all the posts have a message.. you should check if the post has a message before displaying it