# how to read json data in php codeigniter

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

Following below is the json data which i am sending to php controller by using ajax

```
[  
   {  
      "First":"A,b"
   },
   {  
      "Second":""
   },
   {  
      "Third":""
   },
   {  
      "Fourth":""
   },
   {  
      "Fifth":""
   },
   {  
      "Sixth":""
   },
   {  
      "Seventh":""
   },
   {  
      "Eight":""
   },
   {  
      "Ninth":""
   },
   {  
      "Tenth":""
   }
]
```

how can i read values and stored it in php variable or use loop with above json string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode your json string by using `json_decode()` than you can use `foreach()` loop.

```
print_r(json_decode($jsonString,TRUE)); // will return response in an array

print_r(json_decode($jsonString)); // will return response in an object
```

And you can read the data as:

```
$decoded = json_decode($jsonString,TRUE);

foreach( $decoded as $key => $value ){
    // print values
    // print key
}
```

Comment: yes i already decoded it , but i dont know how to read or extract data from it after decoding

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP built in function `json_decode`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Then access it like an array