# How to parse / read json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am new to PHP, I have some data from API in json format.

[image: JSON Image]

In php i tried

```
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($uri)->send();

$json = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($json as $k=>$val):
    echo '<b>Name: '.$k.'</b></br>';

endforeach;

echo $response;

echo "<br />";

print_r($json);

echo "<br />";

echo ($json["genres"][0]);
```

But I am unable to read the array content. Can someone please help me how to parse this PHP array in a loop. Is there any php library to simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the **foreach** loop in PHP as follows, which worked for me.

```
    foreach(json_data as $key => $val){
        echo $key . ":" . $val;
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Also have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php

Answer (score 0):

firstly you wrongly used php's foreach, second you have to use $json['genres'] to access the inner array

```
foreach($json['genres'] as $k=>$val)
{
    echo $k.':'.$val['id'].'_'.$val['name'];
}
```