# PHP JSON value from URL

Tags: php, json, api

I am using the OpenWeather API. I saved it in `$jsonobj`, but don't know how to access weather details. I don't know how `[]` and `{}` differs and what they actually mean.

My code is here:

```
<?php
    $name_of_city = "mathura";
    $request = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=my_key&q='.$name_of_city;
    $response  = file_get_contents($request);
    $jsonobj  = json_decode($response,true);
    print_r($jsonobj);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Comment: Please don't YELL, and please avoid posting textual information as an image. Images aren't searchable, can't be copied-and-pasted, and offer poor accessibility. And please **_never_** post a text image as a JPEG. That's a horrible format for text. If you absolutely must post an image of text, use a PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

`json_decode($response,true);`

It converts the json to array so you can access it like below:

```
$name_of_city = "mathura";
$request = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=my_key&q='.$name_of_city;
$response  = file_get_contents($request);
$jsonobj  = json_decode($response,true);
foreach($jsonobj['weather'] as $weather){
    echo $weather['main'] .":". $weather['description'];//Clear:clear sky
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` represents arrays and `{}` represents objects, so in your example you have for example an object which contains an array of objects named 'weather' , to access is in PHP after json_decode you can go as simple as :

```
foreach($jsonobj->weather as $weather){
    echo "$weather->main : $weather->description";
}
```

Comment: It show error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\localite\index.php on line 9 I just tried here my code<?php

 $name_of_city = "mathura";
    $request = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=my_key&q='.$name_of_city;
    $response  = file_get_contents($request);
    $jsonobj  = json_decode($response,true);
 
 
 foreach($jsonobj->weather as $weather)
 {
    echo "$weather->main : $weather->description";
}
 
 
?>

Comment: that's because you're telling json_decode to provide you with an associative array instead of objects, simply change  json_decode($response,true); to  json_decode($response); or use $weather['main'] instead of $weather->main