# How to read JSON file using php

Tags: php, json

I have a following JSON File. I have tried accessing it; but, I am getting undefined error. Please suggest how to read it using PHP:

```
"feed": {
   "entry": [
   {
    "id": "679244143963",
    "title": "Nashware Black Travel Kit",
    "description": "Color : Black Material : Others Type : Travel kits Closure : Magnit Button Combo : No Compartment : 4 Dimension (LxHxW) cm : 25X51X7 Disclaimer : Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings Gender : Women ",
    "link": "http://www.sl.com/product/travel-kit/679244143963",
    "image_link": "http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/e/t/MU_COS_BAG_M_1_3x-0b20f.jpg",
    "sub_category_id": "435",
    "sub_category_name": "Travel Accessories",
    "mrp": "700",
    "availability": "in stock",
    "effective_price": "310"
  },
   {
    "id": "679244143963",
    "title": "Nashware Black Travel Kit",
    "description": "Color : Black Material : Others Type : Travel kits Closure : Magnit Button Combo : No Compartment : 4 Dimension (LxHxW) cm : 25X51X7 Disclaimer : Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings Gender : Women ",
    "link": "http://www.sl.com/product/travel-kit/679244143963",
    "image_link": "http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/e/t/MU_COS_BAG_M_1_3x-0b20f.jpg",
    "sub_category_id": "435",
    "sub_category_name": "Travel Accessories",
    "mrp": "700",
    "availability": "in stock",
    "effective_price": "310"
  }
   ]
  }
```

After Entry same as JSON notation Id, title, desc and etc are displayed in array. Any suggestions.

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: It's not my code , I am fetching it using API. It's by snapdeal's top selling products json file.

Comment: @apokryfos Why isn't that valid JSON?

Comment: @DhruviMistry How do you expect us to help with your code if you do not post it here?

Comment: This is the xml file :  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed><entry><id>679244143963</id><title>Nashware Black Travel Kit</title></entry>
<entry><id>645222300642</id><title>Cheston Chb-20 Plastic Air Blower - Red</title></entry></feed>

Comment: @arkascha it's missing opening and closing `{ }`. While I could just say that, getting a malformed JSON is usually a symptom of something else going wrong.

Comment: No, the brackets are _not_ missing. As said above the `"feed":` has to be removed, it is a left over from the XML enclosing as the OP clearly stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your JSON is structured as follows :

```
{"feed" : {
   "entry" : [array of JSON objects]
 }
}
```

So after doing some research, it seems the best way to do it would be to use [RecursiveArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivearrayiterator.getchildren.php). I found the answer on another post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php?rq=1).

```
 <?php

$json = <<< JSON
{
 "feed": {
        "entry": [{
            "id": "679244143963",
            "title": "Nashware Black Travel Kit",
            "description": "Color : Black Material : Others Type : Travel kits Closure : Magnit Button Combo : No Compartment : 4 Dimension (LxHxW) cm : 25X51X7 Disclaimer : Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings Gender : Women ",
            "link": "http://www.sl.com/product/travel-kit/679244143963",
            "image_link": "http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/e/t/MU_COS_BAG_M_1_3x-0b20f.jpg",
            "sub_category_id": "435",
            "sub_category_name": "Travel Accessories",
            "mrp": "700",
            "availability": "in stock",
            "effective_price": "310"
        },
        {
            "id": "679244143963",
            "title": "Nashware Black Travel Kit",
            "description": "Color : Black Material : Others Type : Travel kits Closure : Magnit Button Combo : No Compartment : 4 Dimension (LxHxW) cm : 25X51X7 Disclaimer : Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings Gender : Women ",
            "link": "http://www.sl.com/product/travel-kit/679244143963",
            "image_link": "http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/e/t/MU_COS_BAG_M_1_3x-0b20f.jpg",
            "sub_category_id": "435",
            "sub_category_name": "Travel Accessories",
            "mrp": "700",
            "availability": "in stock",
            "effective_price": "310"
        }]
    }
}
JSON;

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

[Here you can run the code one codepad](http://codepad.org/QF9Rbwxy)

Comment: @DhruviMistry Glad I could help ! (be sure to do some research next time!)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed start and end brackets. Your json should look like:

```
    {
    "feed": {
        "entry": [{
            "id": "679244143963",
            "title": "Nashware Black Travel Kit",
            "description": "Color : Black Material : Others Type : Travel kits Closure : Magnit Button Combo : No Compartment : 4 Dimension (LxHxW) cm : 25X51X7 Disclaimer : Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings Gender : Women ",
            "link": "http://www.sl.com/product/travel-kit/679244143963",
            "image_link": "http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/e/t/MU_COS_BAG_M_1_3x-0b20f.jpg",
            "sub_category_id": "435",
            "sub_category_name": "Travel Accessories",
            "mrp": "700",
            "availability": "in stock",
            "effective_price": "310"
        },
        {
            "id": "679244143963",
            "title": "Nashware Black Travel Kit",
            "description": "Color : Black Material : Others Type : Travel kits Closure : Magnit Button Combo : No Compartment : 4 Dimension (LxHxW) cm : 25X51X7 Disclaimer : Product colour may slightly vary due to photographic lighting sources or your monitor settings Gender : Women ",
            "link": "http://www.sl.com/product/travel-kit/679244143963",
            "image_link": "http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/e/t/MU_COS_BAG_M_1_3x-0b20f.jpg",
            "sub_category_id": "435",
            "sub_category_name": "Travel Accessories",
            "mrp": "700",
            "availability": "in stock",
            "effective_price": "310"
        }]
    }
}
```

Or you have to use below code:

```
$obj = json_decode("{" . $json . "}");
```

Comment: More likely the `feed` key is part of the APIs response structure and should be removed.

Comment: Hi, Vircom , I converted xml file into Json , and the code I have written is the one I got from the online converter , I don't know much. Can you please share how to access it.

Comment: @arkascha , sure will do that , As I don't know where to start I simply paste that here. Do help if you can in accessing it.

Comment: JSON content, that you pasted is valid. But php require additional brackets. Could you paste part of your code that not working correct ?

Comment: I have tried this 2 options :                                                      
foreach($result as $re){
echo $re.feed.entry["title"];
//  echo $re[feed]->[entry]{title};
}

Comment: So how about:  foreach($obj->feed->entry as $entry) {
    echo $entry->title;
}