# How to access to these data with a foreach in PHP

Tags: php, json, string

I begin in PHP. I would like to access on these data from my table with a foreach but I can't.

I tried to follow this post but it does not work ([How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)).

My data, stored in a column

```
[
 {"type":"Travaux dirigés","hour":"15"},
 {"type":"Travaux pratique","hour":"30"}
]
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: _it does not work_ - That's a start. _What_ have you tried? Did you get an error message? Let's see it: update your question with your code

Comment: Please show more php code for better assistance.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parse json like this, [live demo](https://eval.in/788433).

```
$string = '[
     {"type":"Travaux dirigés","hour":"15"},
     {"type":"Travaux pratique","hour":"30"}
    ]';

    $data = json_decode($string, true);

    foreach ($data as $v) {
        echo $v['hour'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = '[
     {"type":"Travaux dirigés","hour":"15"},
     {"type":"Travaux pratique","hour":"30"}
    ]';

$getdata = json_decode($data, TRUE);

?>


<ul>
<?php
    foreach($getdata as $value){ 
?>
    <li>
    <p> <?php echo $value['type']; ?>
    <p> <?php echo $value['hour']; ?> 
    </li>
<?php
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$json = '[
     {"type":"Travaux dirigés","hour":"15"},
     {"type":"Travaux pratique","hour":"30"}
    ]';

    $data = json_decode($json);

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        print "row=> " . $row->hour;
    }
```

Comment: Two things to note about this: You probably need to use `$row->hour` instead of `$row['hour']` (because you didn't specify it as an associative array, second parameter to `true`), and there's missing a semicolon on that line. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php Not my downvote though!