# PHP Get Array Value from JSON Not working

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to get the URLS from the JSON below.

```
$jsonArray = {
     "uuid": "signed",
    "PreSigned": "{'url': ['www.g.com', 'www.o.com']"}
```

I tried this `$jsonArray -> PreSigned[0]->url`

And it didn't work

Comment: I'm not sure what language you're showing in your snippet. Seems pseudocode php with javascript, but you need to know that PreSigned is an object and url is an array. so try `$jsonArray -> PreSigned->url[0]` which would return 'www.g.com' if it works. Edit: seems like PreSigned would need one more parse pass on it as it is now json encoded string. (And it is not valid json) It is all kind confusing.

Comment: Use `json_decode` converting the json string to php array, `json_decode($jsonArray, true)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4343596/6521116

Comment: That is not valid PHP. At all. You need to do something else with what you got, simple as that.