# Select value from JSON inside Laravel Blade

Tags: php, json, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel with blade and vuejs. Using a controller for a list I am receving the correct response with all the users data to show.

Some of this fields are json data and I can't understand how to retrieve single value.

```
`@foreach ($lista as $freelance)
  <md-table-row>
    <md-table-cell>
      {{ $freelance->regione }}
     </md-table-cell>
  </md-table-row>
@endforeach`
```

$freelance->regione is a JSON, correctly shown in the page as:

```
`{"text": "Veneto", "value": "Veneto"}`
```

My question is, how can I get the single value of the JSON response and not all the data? Preferably without loops...I know that I can use a new loop for it but possible no..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this in your controller before passing the `$lista` variable** to view do this.

```
foreach($lista as list)
{

 //we will decode the variable befoe passing it to view
 $list->regione = json_decode($list->regione, true);


}
```

**and then pass the variable to your view like :**

```
    return View::make('your_view_name', compact('lista'));
```

**then in your blade view.**

```
`@foreach ($lista as $freelance)
  <md-table-row>
    <md-table-cell>
      {{ $freelance->regione['text'] }}
     </md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell>
      {{ $freelance->regione['value'] }}
     </md-table-cell>
  </md-table-row>
@endforeach`
```

Comment: seems good Sapnesh...I've made as you said and in the List Controller I've seen the right value...unfortunately the compact($lista) throws me this error: Call to a member function total() on array...

Comment: @Murphz oh sorry, you don't need to include `$` when using compact, it  was a typo. updated  now

Comment: That'is Sapnesh, it works! I have had to correct some errors in your code but maybe it's just my platform. The json_decode result cannot be applied to $list->regione as it only accept string and not array, used a temp value solved it. After that, using the compact('lista') I am now able to retrieve the correct value in the blade template using just $freelance->regione...thank you again sir!

Answer (score 0):

There are functions laravel blade template allow use directly.  You need to decode the json string in order to get the value in it.

```
@foreach ($lista as $freelance)
 <md-table-row>
    <md-table-cell>
        {{ json_decode($freelance->regione)->value }}
    </md-table-cell>
 </md-table-row>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That’s probably because some of your regione json string in the loop may not contain value key

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode to parse the json string, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343691/6521116) for json parse

```
{{ json_decode($freelance->regione, true)['value'] }}
```

Comment: Yes, tried that..but inside blade is not working to me, using json_decode in the controller as Sapnesh wrote seems working good...