# How to get value from JSON php

Tags: php, json, web-services

This is my JSON.

```
{
  "OUT_STAT": "200",
  "OUT_MESS": "SUKSES",
  "OUT_DATA": [{
      "id_doc_proj": "4"
    }]
}
```

My Questions are:
1. How to get OUT_STAT value?
2. How to get id_doc_proj value?

I am sorry if my questions are silly because i am new at get value from JSON.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I am sorry if you are saying i duplicated [Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php). I have tried code from there but i don't get any JSON from my response. I don't know where is the mistake. If you want to help, this is my php script.

```
<?php
    $file_path = "";
    $id_project = "16";
    $p_id_doc_proj = "50";
    $id_doc_type = "1";
    $id_user = "4";

    $url = $file_path.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $url)){
        $ws = "http://172.xx.x.xx:xxxx/rest/com/acc/uw/in/httprest/apponline/uploadtrough/UploadImage/$id_project/$p_id_doc_proj/$id_doc_type/$id_user/$url";

        $opts = array('http'=>array('header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);

        $arrayLog=array();
        $data1 = file_get_contents($ws, false, $context);
        $result = json_decode($data1, true);;

        //$result = array("result" => "success");
    }else{
        $result = array("result" => "error");
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

The result should show my JSON above but it was null. Any answers will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use json_decode() and then get the value by array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343596/6521116)

Comment: $a='{
  "OUT_STAT": "200",
  "OUT_MESS": "SUKSES",
  "OUT_DATA": [{
      "id_doc_proj": "4"
    }]
}';
$a=json_decode($a);

echo $out_stat = $a->OUT_STAT
$out_data =$a->OUT_DATA;
foreach ($out_data as $key => $value) {
 echo $id_doc_proj = $value->id_doc_proj;
 # code...
}

Comment: Sorry if i duplicated, i have updated my question @KrisRoofe

Answer (score 1):

```
$data="{
  "OUT_STAT": "200",
  "OUT_MESS": "SUKSES",
  "OUT_DATA": [{
      "id_doc_proj": "4"
    }]
}";

$op=json_decode($data, true);

echo $op['OUT_STAT'];
echo $op['OUT_DATA'][0]['id_doc_proj'];
```

http://php.net/json_deocde. it will make output as associative array. you can then use the result as you would do with an assoc array. you can also use `var_dump()` to introspect the structure.

Comment: you are like no matter whether user say it is duplicate question, i ll give the simple answer to increase my repo

Comment: @BunkerBoy check the post time and flag time before you start blaming people.

Comment: check the @ Kris Roofe comment time

Answer (score -1):

you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert json to array or object:

```
$json = '{
  "OUT_STAT": "200",
  "OUT_MESS": "SUKSES",
  "OUT_DATA": [{
      "id_doc_proj": "4"
    }]
}';

$object = json_decode($json);
$out_stat = $object->OUT_STAT;
$id_doc_proj = $object->OUT_DATA[0]->id_doc_proj;
```

Comment: you are like no matter whether user say it is duplicate question, i ll give the simple answer to increase my repo