# json_decode doesn't work on my string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have JSON Object which I have encoded like so

```
{
"id": "",
"steps": [
             {
        "target": "purchase_order_items_itemmaster_id",
        "title": "",
        "placement": "",
        "content": "",
        "xoffset": "",
        "yoffset": ""
              }
         ]
}
$JSONData = json_encode($finalData,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I am taking this JSON data and storing it in a file like so

```
File::put("path","var tour = \n [ \n\t $JSONData \n ];");
```

which looks something like this in the file

```
    var tour = 
 [ 
     {
    "id": "",
    "steps": [
        {
            "target": "purchase_order_items_itemmaster_id",
            "title": "",
            "placement": "",
            "content": "",
            "xoffset": "",
            "yoffset": ""
        }
    ]
}
 ];
```

Now I am reading it back form the second line like so

```
 [ 
     {
    "id": "",
    "steps": [
        {
            "target": "purchase_order_items_itemmaster_id",
            "title": "",
            "placement": "",
            "content": "",
            "xoffset": "",
            "yoffset": ""
        }
    ]
}
 ];
```

The problem is when I want to decode it back it doesn't happen,this is how I am trying to do that,

```
$lines = file_get_contents("path",NULL,NULL,10);

$a = json_decode($lines);
```

Now according to expected output the $a should have the decoded data but it has null.

Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php what does it print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the second parameter `true` for recursively decoding

```
$a = json_decode(chop($lines,";"),true);
```

check the php mannual here [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is the semicolon at the end of the JSON you've read back in from the file. Try chopping that off before attempting `json_decode`:

```
$a = json_decode(rtrim($lines, ";"));
```

Comment: yeah invalid json data may be cause for json_decode failure

Answer (score 1):

It will be

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://example.com/example.json/');
 $json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array
```

See the post 
[Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

try to save data in file like

```
$fp = fopen('path', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($JSONData)); //if $JSONData is in string 
fclose($fp);
```

instead of

```
File::put("path","var tour = \n [ \n\t $JSONData \n ];");
```

//and  read like

```
// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('path');

//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

//Print data
print_r($json_data);
```