# Parsing through json string php

Tags: php, json

im new with JSON and have had massive struggle trying to parse this JSON

```
    {
    "730": {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "price_overview": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "initial": 1499,
                "final": 1499,
                "discount_percent": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried different approaches but still struggle to get the value of initial in price_overview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343691/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), and then, just use the `dictionary` that is generated to grab the value. Like this:

```
$json = <<< JSON
    {
    "730": {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "price_overview": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "initial": 1499,
                "final": 1499,
                "discount_percent": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
JSON;

$json_a = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json_a['730']['data']['price_overview']['initial'];
```

**CodePad**

http://codepad.org/i1ELBxd9

**Further Reading**

[Using JSON with PHP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm)

Comment: Thanks, appreciated

Comment: @Bradm No problem, just try to do some more research before asking!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$data = '{"730":{"success":true,"data":{"price_overview":{"currency":"USD","initial":1499,"final":1499,"discount_percent":0}}}}';

$json = json_decode(trim($data), true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($json[730][data][price_overview]);
echo '</pre>';
```