# Getting Data From JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get the data out of this JSON format to be able to show on screen problem is I am not sure how I would be able to do this as I have tried multiple ways such as :

```
$stats = json_decode($result);
// var_dump($stats);
echo $stats->elo;
```

And nothing is working I am unsure how to get the data due to the [], as I have never worked with this before. As shown below is a small piece of the data I need to be able to get into.

```
[{"_id":{"championId":51,"role":"DUO_CARRY"},"elo":"BRONZE","patch":"7.11","championId":51,"positions":{"deaths":3,"winRates":6,"minionsKilled":2,"previousOverallPerformanceScore":6}}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to use foreach to get that value out from that array

Comment: In its most basic form - `$stats[0]->elo;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343691/6521116)

Comment: https://eval.in/816160

Comment: Thanks been looking for ages could not find something similar

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple rule of thumb when processing JSON. First just decode it and print it using a `print_r()` so you can see its structure easily

```
$s = '[{"_id":{"championId":51,"role":"DUO_CARRY"},"elo":"BRONZE","patch":"7.11","championId":51,"positions":{"deaths":3,"winRates":6,"minionsKilled":2,"previousOverallPerformanceScore":6}}]';

$stats = json_decode($s);

print_r($stats);
```

Which will show you in this case

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [championId] => 51
                    [role] => DUO_CARRY
                )
            [elo] => BRONZE
            [patch] => 7.11
            [championId] => 51
            [positions] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [deaths] => 3
                    [winRates] => 6
                    [minionsKilled] => 2
                    [previousOverallPerformanceScore] => 6
                )
        )
)
```

So now you know there is an array containing in this case only one object

So to show `elo` you could do a simple

```
echo $stats[0]->elo;    // BRONZE
```

But as it is an array of object it may be better to assume in some cases there will be more than one stat so you could process it in a foreach loop like this

```
foreach ($stats as $stat) {
    echo $stat->elo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get more than one array data in that json use foreach as follow

```
foreach ($stats as $row) {
    echo $row->elo;
}
```

if you want to get only first record then use `$stats[0]->elo;`

Answer (score 0):

Don't  konw if i understood  you correctly (you want to get data in array ? ) ,
but try

```
$stats = json_decode($result,true);
var_dump($stats);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output of json_decode is an array of objects. So you have to use index to access the array element first, then access the property of object with `$array[0]->elo` [Live demo.](https://eval.in/816160)

```
$string = '[{"_id":{"championId":51,"role":"DUO_CARRY"},"elo":"BRONZE","patch":"7.11","championId":51,"positions":{"deaths":3,"winRates":6,"minionsKilled":2,"previousOverallPerformanceScore":6}}]';
print_r(json_decode($string)[0]->elo);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get associative array you should use `$stats = json_decode($result, true); 
var_dump($stats);` And you'll get

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      '_id' => 
        array (size=2)
          'championId' => int 51
          'role' => string 'DUO_CARRY' (length=9)
      'elo' => string 'BRONZE' (length=6)
      'patch' => string '7.11' (length=4)
      'championId' => int 51
      'positions' => 
        array (size=4)
          'deaths' => int 3
          'winRates' => int 6
          'minionsKilled' => int 2
          'previousOverallPerformanceScore' => int 6
```

For getting elements get the first key of array by `$stats[0]` or with loop. Ex. `$stats[0]['elo']`