# How can I access my nested array key in codeignigter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
"data": [
            {
                "pid": "81",
                "fname": "Parth",
                "lname": "Tandel",
                "pfname": "Parth",
                "plname": "Tandel",
                "userprofilephoto": "/Images/ProfilePictures/18/DSC_0164.JPG",
                "parentprofilephoto": "/Images/ProfilePictures/18/DSC_0164.JPG",
                "type": "ALBUM",
                "likescount": "1",
                "commentscount": "1",
                "sharecount": "0",
                "sharepid": null,
                "uaid": "18",
                "ownerid": "18",
                "parentid": null,
                "title": "newalbum2",
                "description": "",
                "sharedescription": null,
                "imagepath": null,
                "previewurl": null,
                "previewtitle": null,
                "previewshortdescription": null,
                "previewimageurl": null,
                "createdon": "2017-05-29 15:44:04",
                "posttype": "5",
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "pcid": "21",
                        "uaid": "31",
                        "comment": "this is dope",
                        "fname": "maulik",
                        "lname": "kanani",
                        "profPicturepath": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/003dbb32079ee5ff19ed75476f562bd1",
                        "createdon": "2017-06-15 23:50:36"
                    }
                ],
                "albumimages": [
                    {
                        "imagepath": "/Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-36.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "imagepath": "/Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-361.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "imagepath": "/Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-363.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "imagepath": "/Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-364.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "imagepath": "/Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-365.png"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

My PHP code

```
<?php 
  for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($value->albumimages); $i++) 
  { 
    $x = count($value->albumimages); 
    switch($x) 
    { 
      break; 
      default: 
        if($i == 0 || $i == 1) 
        { 
          echo '<div class="col-sm-6 pads5 marb10"> <img class="full" src="'.getapiPath().$imgs->imagepath.'"> </div>'; 
        } 
        break; 
    } 
  } 
?>
```

I want albumimages->imagepath

Comment: i want in my foreach loop and codeignigter view

Comment: how i can implement this?

Comment: show you controller and view code pls ...

Comment: <?php
          for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($value->albumimages); $i++) { 
                                          $x = count($value->albumimages);
       switch($x) {
                                                   break;
                 default:
        if($i == 0 || $i == 1)
            {
                                                      echo '<div class="col-sm-6 pads5 marb10">
                 <img class="full" src="'.getapiPath().$imgs->imagepath.'">
                  </div>';
         }
              break;
  }
        } ?>

Comment: [Parsing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343596/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($value->albumimages); $i++) {
    $x = count($value->albumimages);
    switch($x) {
        default: 
            if($i == 0 || $i == 1) 
            { 
              echo '<div class="col-sm-6 pads5 marb10"> <img class="full" src="'.getapiPath().$value->albumimages[$i]->imagepath.'"> </div>'; 
            } 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: To improve your answer maybe you can add some text to describe your solution

Comment: for loop will run till size of albumimages  and "$x" are count the case of for loop

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is json_decode($data, `true`);

This makes the json data an array that you can use like `var_dump($data["albumimages"])`

Working example: https://3v4l.org/Q9lkW
And to loop through the links you can do foreach, https://3v4l.org/9rRSF

Answer (score 0):

The data is in json format so convert the data into php object by using 'json_encode()' function. This function converts the json data into php object the access the property by using php object operator.

```
$data = json_encode('your_json_string');
//and access like this
$data[0]->albumimages
```

You can use the foreach loop to access the 'imagepath' like this

```
//get the albumsimages
$albumimages = $data[0]->albumimages;

//then use foreach to access the imagepath like this
foreach($albumimages as $image) {
    echo $image->imagepath ."\n";
}
```

Check out working example here
[PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07e276d299e0a9e0c8d6c92558e09c6871dd330f)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$a = json_decode('YOUR JSON STRING',true);
foreach($a['data'][0] as $key => $value){
    if($key == 'albumimages'){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++){
            foreach($value[$i] as $k => $v){
                echo "Key: ".$k." Value: ".$v."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be like this

Key: imagepath Value: /Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-36.png

Key: imagepath Value: /Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-361.png

Key: imagepath Value: /Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-363.png

Key: imagepath Value: /Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-364.png

Key: imagepath Value: /Images/18/Albums/newalbum2/Screenshot_from_2017-06-12_15-11-365.png