# Parse json data from <script> tag using simple_html_dom library

Tags: php, json, dom

I have this data in the html source.

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    [{"@context:":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"Movie","name":"My First Movie"}]
    </script>
```

Now i want to parse from this json data like type, movie using simple_html_dom php library. I have gone upto

```
    $des = $html->find('script', 1)->innertext;
    $desDecode = json_decode($des);
```

Using this I got `[{"@context:":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"Movie","name":"My First Movie"}]`But after this I am confused how to get value like Movie or name. I cant find the json object name here from where I can start. Please give some light on this.

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

Comment: @AndréDion — http://i.imgur.com/k7U8MtX.png

Comment: @Quentin, I'm aware. It should be pretty obvious reading the documentation what the shape of the object is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code i think you got json response like this.

```
$html = '<script type="application/ld+json">
[{"@context:":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"Movie","name":"My First Movie"}]
</script>';

 $des = strip_tags($html);
$desDecode = json_decode($des);

print_r($desDecode);
```

Comment: Totally irrevalent. Read the question carefully.

Comment: This rewrites the **working** code from the question (in a way that is much more fragile) without addressing the problem the question is asking about at all.